# Is possible monitor the VPN's bandwidth with Check_MK? How?

Tags: vpn, monitoring, bandwidth, juniper, check-mk

I would like monitor the bandwidth in the VPN of Juniper SSG5 with Check_MK. Is possible? How?

For the moment I am monitoring the status with the check automatic ([check_mk-juniper_screenos_vpn](https://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_check_juniper_screenos_vpn.html)). However I want monitor the bandwidth.

I hope that anybody can help me. Thanks.